# Stripe Pre-Checkout Timeout Error while making a Test Payment from Telegram Bot

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, telegram-bot

i have being building a telegram bot with nodejs where people can send in a url of a tweet and if it contains a media of type video. it downloads it and sends it to the user. Thats the purpose, which i already completed.

The problem i have is with setting a paywall on this bot account so that after 2 or 3 request, the user interacting with the bot have to make a payment to continue.

so i used the [sendInvoice](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendinvoice) method.

FYI, i'm not using any external librarys, i'm directly interacting with the telegram api endpoints.

I'm using stripe for payments in test mode (my acc is unverified if that helps). the problem i have is as you can see in this picture:

[This is whats happening/showing after some time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm69E.png)

After i send the invoice, then the user clicks the pay button and adds all the necessary card details then after hitting the pay. it keeps buffering and then time outs.

I also tried the [createInvoiceLink](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#createinvoicelink) method and the same thing happened.

Ofcourse its some mistake in my solution, but i dont know where that is. May be i have to use a webhook or something to catch the checkout initiation/completion. but how can i let the Telegram api know about my payment webhook path (assuming something like that exists).

The only one i found is the method [setWebhook](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook) which is an alternative approach for polling. And that is what i am doing locally with ngrok.

A Part of my code, this is an abstract version of the functionality:

```
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const botToken = process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN;
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Webhook endpoint that receives incoming messages (exposed via ngrok)
app.post(`/bot${botToken}`, async (req, res) => {
  const { message } = req.body;

  console.log({ message });

  if (message && message.text) {
    const chatId = message.chat.id;
    const messageText = message.text;

    // after successfull 3 responses from the bot, send an invoice

    const invoiceRes = await sendInvoice(
      chatId,
      "Premium Subscription",
      "Unlock premium content with a subscription.",
      "premium_subscription",
      process.env.PROVIDER_TOKEN,
      "subscription",
      "USD",
      [{ label: "Subscription", amount: 1000 }],
    );

    console.log(JSON.stringify(invoiceRes, null, 2));
  }

  res.status(200).end();
});

async function sendInvoice(
  chatId,
  title,
  description,
  payload,
  providerToken,
  startParameter,
  currency,
  prices,
) {
  const apiUrl = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${botToken}/sendInvoice`;

  const invoice = {
    chat_id: chatId,
    title: title,
    description: description,
    payload: payload,
    provider_token: providerToken,
    start_parameter: startParameter,
    currency: currency,
    prices: prices,
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(invoice),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    // console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("There was a problem sending the invoice:", error);
    return error.message;
  }
}
```

I googled a lot to find some answers, there isnt anything specified in the [payment section of the docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments) either rather than getting the provider token (not anything specifically if i have to do on the stripe account dashboard like adding a webhook endpoint, even if that was the case how would telegram know that is the webhook it should communicate too)

I have been mentioning webhook a lot, because in my mind i am assuming that is my missing solution. if it isnt i'm sorry for doing so. I don't have much experience with stripe or building a telegram bot.

I hope i could get some help with this problem. even a small guidance will be enough if you are busy. just something i can go with that's all i ask.